# A general way to enter prior distribution information into function?

Tags: r, distribution

I want to enter prior distribution information into a function. I can enter individual distributions manually by modifying function body but I'm searching for a general way of doing this?
For example, I want to plot posterior distribution of a function given prior distribution.

```
set.seed(1)
n <- 10
pars <- runif(n)
y <- NA
for (i in 1:n)
  y[i] <- rbinom(1,1, prob=pars[i])

plotPosterior <- function(pars,y,mean=0,vari=4)
{  
  x <- seq(-3,3,by = .1)
  logLik <- NA
  for (i in seq(along.with=x))
    logLik[i] <- sum(y*log(1 + exp(pars-x[i])) - (y-1)*log(1 + exp(x[i]-pars)))

  posterior <- logLik * dnorm(x,mean=mean,sd=sqrt(vari))
  plot(x,posterior,type="l")
}
plotPosterior(pars,y,0,4)
```

I can able to enter mean an variance parameters for normal distribution. But if I want to use, for example, beta distribution I have to rewrite the function. Instead I want a way to enter distributions like "`dnorm(mean=xx,sd=yy)`" or "`dbeta(shape1=xx, shape2=yy)`"...
Only viable way I see is entering `dnorm(x,mean=mean,sd=sqrt(vari))` into function as an input. But I don't want to pre-specify `x` beforehand. Is there any other way to do this?

Comment: if I understand well, you could replace `dnorm()` in your function by `fun(x, ...)`, where `fun` and `...` are passed to `plotPosterior(pars, y, fun = dnorm, ...)`

Comment: This is exactly what I have wanted. I changed function header to `plotPosterior <- function(pars,y,fun = dnorm,...)`, related function line to `posterior <- logLik * fun(x, ...)`. And when I call `plotPosterior(pars,y,fun = dbeta,shape1=2,shape2=3)` it just worked as I wanted.   I think I need to grasp this `...` better.  Thanks a lot.

Comment: an alternative way is to write `plotPosterior(pars,y, fun = dbeta, params.fun = list(shape1=2,shape2=3))` and call it with `posterior <- logLik * do.call(fun, c(x, params.fun))`.

Comment: I was about to write how to set defaults to function, and this second method seemed to be just for that. But when I changed the first line of the function above to `plotPosterior <- function(pars,y,fun = dnorm, params.fun = list(mean=0,sd=2))`, 7th line of the function to `posterior <- logLik * do.call(fun, c(x, params.fun))` and try to call it with `plotPosterior(pars,y)`, I got an error. Method on first comment just worked fine but I don't know how to set defaults to standard normal distribution with that.

Comment: sorry, you need `posterior <- logLik * do.call(fun, c(list(x), params.fun))`; I often get bitten by that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For the sake of clarity, here's a working solution extracted from the comments,

```
set.seed(1)
n <- 10
pars <- runif(n)
y <- NA
for (i in 1:n)
  y[i] <- rbinom(1,1, prob=pars[i])

plotPosterior <- function(pars,y, fun = dnorm, 
                          params.fun = list(mean=0, sd=2))
{  
  x <- seq(-3,3,by = .1)
  logLik <- NA
  for (i in seq(along.with=x))
    logLik[i] <- sum(y*log(1 + exp(pars-x[i])) - (y-1)*log(1 + exp(x[i]-pars)))

  posterior <- logLik * do.call(fun, c(list(x), params.fun))
  plot(x,posterior,type="l")
}

plotPosterior(pars, y) # default params and function
plotPosterior(pars, y, fun = dbeta, params.fun = list(shape1=2, shape2=3))
```